# Why isn't autocomplete of local packages working in Atom editor?

Tags: go, atom-editor

Autocomplete (go-plus) works fine in Atom for standard library imports, but whenever I try to import my own packages It simply doesn't work.

My package structure goes like this:

```
.
├── bin
├── pkg
└── src
    └── Test
        ├── MyPackage
        │   └── hello.go
        └── main.go
```

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "Test/MyPackage"
)

func main() {
    hello.SayHello("World")
}
```

**hello.go**

```
package hello

import "fmt"

const Msg = "Hello "

func SayHello(name string) {
    fmt.Printf("%v%v!\n", Msg, name)
}
```

The file compiles fine, but in `main.go` the `hello` package does not invoke any autocompletion in Atom, so what could be the problem?

Comment: this belongs on go-plus' issue tracker.

Comment: have you tried `go get github.com/algo/package`? *edit* if your packages are already in your gopath this won't help

Comment: @Plato Yup, already in gopath.

Comment: I'm using go-plus in atom too and it works just fine. In order to make import works, the tools used by go-plus need to find all your package inside the $GOPATH directory. So, if $GOPATH is correctly set, it should work. Don't forget that any imported package that is not used in your code, will be automatically removed from the import clause (if you configured go-plus do to that on save).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is addressed in the README.md of the go-plus package:

> First of all, make sure
>   [autocomplete-plus](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-plus) is
>   present on your setup. Go-plus provides autocompletion through
>   [gocode](https://github.com/nsf/gocode) tool, so you should ensure
>   it's in PATH and available.
>
> If you can't get autocompletion for the user-defined packages working,
>   while it's there for packages from standard library, it's likely a
>   trivial gocode-related issue. Try running `gocode set`. Some expected
>   output'd be: `propose-builtins false lib-path "" autobuild false
>   force-debug-output "" package-lookup-mode "go"`
>
> *What you gotta do is switching autobuild to true, by running `gocode
>   set autobuild true`. Check autocompletion now, it must be working
>   right.*

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause is the `gocode` daemon is not working properly (either it is due to an update of Go or multiple `gocode` daemons). Closing the daemon may help.
`gocode close`